# Selecting all players objects ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, object, selector

Im just starting to use Objective C and I was wondering what was the proper syntax to select all other players to set the isActive property to NO. Thanks!

```
- (void) playerBuzzedIn: (XGPlayer *) activePlayer
{
    if (activePlayer) {
        activePlayer.isActive = YES;
    }
    else
       //set all other isActive = NO
    self.currentGameState = results;
}
```

Im thinking something like this, is that right:

```
for (XGPlayer *player in self.players) {
player.isActive = NO;
}
```

Comment: If, in the class implementing `-playerBuzzedIn:`, you have a `players` `@property` which is an `NSArray` of `XGPlayer` objects, then, yes, the code you've suggested is correct.  Have you tried it out?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a list of all the players; lets assume it's this:

```
NSMutableArray *_allplayers = ...;
```

Then in your method you can set all players to inactive apart from the one who's just buzzed in:

```
- (void) playerBuzzedIn: (XGPlayer *) activePlayer
{
    if (activePlayer)
    {
        for (XGPlayer *player in _allPlayers)
        {
            player.isActive = activePlayer == player;   // Or perhaps [activePlayer isEqual:player] ?
        }
    }
    self.currentGameState = results;
}
```

Another approach is to keep a pointer to the currently active player:

In .h file:

```
@interface Whatever : NSObject
{
    XGPlayer *_activePlayer = nil;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic, readonly) XGPlayer *activePlayer;

@end
```

In .m file:

```
// Private Methods
@interface Whatever ()
- (void)setActivePlayer:(XGPlayer *)activePlayer
@end

@implementation Whatever

@synthesize activePlayer = _activePlayer;

// Private setter method
- (void)setActivePlayer:(XGPlayer *)activePlayer
{
    [activePlayer retain];     // If not using ARC
    [_activePlayer release];   // If not using ARC
    _activePlayer = activePlayer;
}

- (void) playerBuzzedIn: (XGPlayer *) activePlayer
{
    self.activePlayer.isActive = NO;
    activePlayer.isActive = YES;
    self.activePlayer = activePlayer;
    self.currentGameState = results;
}
```